# container fails to start in swarm mode

Tags: docker-swarm

I tried to start the docker service using swarm mode, but I am not able to connect to port 8080

```
~ $ docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                  PORTS
3tdzofpn6qo5        vigilant_wescoff    replicated          0/1                 shantanu/abc:latest   *:8080->8080/tcp

~ $ docker service ps 3tdzofpn6qo5
ID                  NAME                     IMAGE                  NODE                                          DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE             ERROR               PORTS
iki0t3x1oqmz        vigilant_wescoff.1       shantanuo/abc:latest   ip-172-31-4-142.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Ready               Ready 1 second ago                
z88nyixy7u10         \_ vigilant_wescoff.1   shantanu/abc:latest   ip-172-31-4-142.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Shutdown            Complete 5 minutes ago            
zf4fac2a4dlh         \_ vigilant_wescoff.1   shantanu/abc:latest   ip-172-31-4-142.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Shutdown            Complete 11 minutes ago           
zzqj4lldmxox         \_ vigilant_wescoff.1   shantanu/abc:latest   ip-172-31-6-134.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Shutdown            Complete 14 minutes ago           
z8eknet7oirq         \_ vigilant_wescoff.1   shantanu/abc:latest   ip-172-31-20-50.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Shutdown            Complete 17 minutes ago
```

I used docker for aws (community version)

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/#docker-community-edition-ce-for-aws

But I guess that should not make any difference and the container should work. I have tested it using docker run command it works as expected.

In case of swarm mode, how do I know what exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use `docker events` on managers to see what the orchestrator is doing (but you can't see the history).
2. You can use `docker events` on workers to see what containers/networks/volumes etc. are doing (but you can't see the history).
3. You can look at the `docker service logs` to see current and past container logs
4. You can use `docker container inspect` to see the exit (error) code of the stopped containers in that service task list.